# Not the typical "TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'" issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I've scoured all the other answers I could find here on SO and I'm still hitting a weird issue here. It's the same old "TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'" error that many of you have most likely come across before, where you are expecting an object but getting an array, or vice versa. We are currently on Angular 1.1.5, if this makes a difference. Here is my service:

```
// my Suggestion service
angular.module('suggestionServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Suggestion', ['$resource', 'Utility', function ($resource, Utility) {
return $resource('/appointments/suggestions/json',
  {},
  {
    'query': {
      method: 'POST',
      isArray: true,
      headers: Utility.headers
    }
  });
}]);
```

When I initially call my query through the resolve in the router, like so:

```
// my controller
var AddAppointmentCtrl = app.controller('AddAppointmentCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    '$q',
    'Utility',
    'suggestions',
    'date',
    'Suggestion',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $q, Utility, suggestions, date, Suggestion) {

    // lots of other stuff

}

// this is loaded in through the resolve property of my router
AddAppointmentCtrl.getLists = {
    suggestions: ['Utility', '$q', 'Suggestion', function ( Utility, $q, Suggestion ) {
    Utility.loader.start("Loading suggestions...");
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Suggestion.query({}, function (successData) {
      deferred.resolve(successData);
      console.log(successData);
      Utility.loader.end();
    }, function (errorData) {
      console.log(errorData);
      deferred.reject(errorData);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }]
};
```

This yields the results I expect and the rest of my code performs as expected as well:

```
[{"Employees":[{"account_id":"1330","first_name":"Barack","last_name":"Obama"},{"account_id":"1376","first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Biden"}],"Date":"2014-03-19","Grade":66.6666666667,"Appointments":[],"Superlatives":{"isWithinOneWeek":1,"isWithinTwoWeeks":0,"isNotWithinTwoWeeks":0,"isAlreadyWorking":0,"hasGoodAvailability":1,"recentCleaning":0},"Availability":[{"start":"28800","end":"61200"}]}]
```

But then, when I send some data along in the body of my request to update my array of suggestions by accessing it like this:

```
// this is from my controller above, in the "lots of other stuff" area
$scope.suggestionRequest = new Suggestion();
$scope.suggestionRequest.client_id = null;
$scope.suggestionRequest.date = null;
$scope.suggestionRequest.dow = null;
$scope.suggestionRequest.emp_array = [];
$scope.suggestionRequest.team_length = 2;
$scope.suggestionRequest.start = null;
$scope.suggestionRequest.end = null;
$scope.suggestionRequest.$query();
```

This throws the "TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'". However, the call is actually working and returning this in my Network tab:

```
[{"Employees":[{"account_id":"1375","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Palin"},{"account_id":"1368","first_name":"John","last_name":"McCain"}],"Date":"2014-03-22","Grade":60,"Appointments":[],"Superlatives":{"isWithinOneWeek":1,"isWithinTwoWeeks":0,"isNotWithinTwoWeeks":0,"isAlreadyWorking":0,"hasGoodAvailability":1,"recentCleaning":0},"Availability":[{"start":"28800","end":"61200"}]}]
```

Does anyone see an obvious mistake that I am missing? Any help offered would be immensely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is the error thrown before or after the server returns the request?

Comment: Factories (services) in angular are singletons. Normally the factory is created when it is needed, or when it is injected. You may have to show more of your code, like the controller where you are using the service.

Comment: Is it possible $query is choking on you null values?

Comment: The null values don't seem to be causing it as I've tried inserting hard values and I get the same error. I've added additional controller code above. As far as I can tell, the error is being thrown after the request returns as it is appearing in my Network tab in dev tools.

Comment: Why in one place you have `new Suggestion` and in other `Suggestion` and in one `$query` and in other `query`?